# Administrator Policy not working on Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

My backend Admin area I want restricted to people in the Admin role.  I read an article saying Policies are the way to go.  However whenever I add the attribute I just get redirected to AccessDenied pages.

I clearly have the role

**Here's the DB**
[image]

**StartUp.cs**

```
        var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireRole("Administrator")
            .Build();


        services.AddMvc(setup =>
        {
            setup.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
        });
```

**Attribute Definition**

```
[Authorize("Administrator")]
```

- So if I am both authenticated, and have the role, why can I not get anywhere?
- How do you name the policy, like Authorize("Administrator") I'm not sure where "Administrator" comes from (the article wasn't clear on that either).

Comment: Even if I remove all the policy stuff and just try to check based on Role Name (this is the legacy way?) it still dumps me to the not authorized page.  [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]

Answer (score 2):

Okay, must have been an old article, or the Role check just outright doesn't work. Policy syntax in the docs seems to work like a champ though.

Startup

```
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
        });
```

Controller

```
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]
public class AdminDashboardController : Controller
```